# Using sensetalk - How to check particular word is present in the text file ? if its available how can we read/print the immediate next line the word

Tags: regex, eggplant

I have tried this code to verify the content of file and I was able to read the content, but I should read the word which is immediate to searching word.

For example in the text file I have some 10 lines of content; in the third line I found the searched word, I should read the immediate next line of searched word. 
Consider this is a text fie content:

```
Hello
how 
are 
you 
I am 
fine
```

I need to search the word `how` is present in the text file , if the `how` word is found, I should read/verify the immediate next line of the word.

The output should be `are`

```
open file "D:\Automation\EGGPlant\Archiecture\Script-Demo.suite\Resources\Demo.txt"

read from file "D:\Automation\EGGPlant\Archiecture\Script-Demo.suite\Resources\Demo.txt" 

put file  "D:\Automation\EGGPlant\Archiecture\Script-Demo.suite\Resources\Demo.txt"  into WiFiInfo
```

Repeat the number of lines of WiFiInfo times:

```
put line repeatindex() of WiFiInfo into output

    if output contains "how" then
        Log "found"
    else 
        Log "Not found"
    end if

end repeat
```

Expected result should be `are`

Comment: This is Eggplant - Sensetalk code

Comment: If this were a *ux-based system, I'd suggest using the `shell` sensetalk command to run this logic in the shell. If that's an option for you, that's what I'd explore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your question

```
Set dataFile to (file ResourcePath("Test.txt"))

set output to "how" // variable to set with the value "how

split dataFile by newline // all the values from the text file will be split and put into a list so that we can access it based on it position

repeat each item of dataFile
    if item repeatindex() of dataFile contains output then // statement check each item with the variable which is containing "how"
        log item repeatindex()+1 of dataFile // repeatindex()+1 will point the next index of current index
        exit repeat // Repeat will exit once the condition is true
    end if
end repeat
```